# Выполнение деления по модулю во вложенном цикле

Tags: java

В Java руководстве для начинающих Шилдта есть задача после второй главы, в которой необходимо написать программу, которая находила бы все простые числа в диапазоне от 2 до 100. Решение в книге предоставляется следующее:

```
    class test1 {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            int x, y; boolean z;
            for(x = 2; x < 100; x++) {
                z = true;
                for(y = 2; y <= (x/y); y++) 
                    if((x % y) == 0) 
                        z = false;
                if(z) 
                    System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

Например, на цикле с X=77 после предыдущей итерации Y=8.Условие вложенного цикла выполняется(8<=77/8), однако инструкция if будет выполнена только при Y=7. Компилятор производит правильное вычисление и не отображает строку. Как определяется значение Y соответствующее выполнению инструкции if((x%y)==0)?

Comment: "однако инструкция if будет выполнена только при Y=7" - ?

Comment: `if((77%7)==0) z=false;
if(z) System.out.println(x);`
строка не отобразится, если же Y=8, то в делении по модулю будет остаток, z сохранит значение true и строка будет выведена, что будет являться ошибкой

Comment: Шилдт что-нибудь писал о форматировании кода?

Comment: Только то, что в Java допускается произвольное форматирование исходного кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((x%y)==0) { z=false; break; }
```

---

> if((77%8)==0) принимает ложное значение, и z остаётся true,

К этому времени `z` уже `false` и останется `false` до конца внутреннего цикла. Поэтому внутренний цикл можно прервать, как только код зайдет в `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Я так и не понял что ты хочешь, но вот моя реализация этого задания. 
 Даже если это не то, пусть будет :)

```
class test1{
  public static void main(String args[]){

    for (int i = 2; i < 100 ; i++) {
      if (!isPrime(i)) System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
  public static boolean isPrime(final int number) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number / 2).anyMatch(i -> number % i == 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Я хочу понять как исключаются лишние значения Х в заданном диапазоне. х=77 не отобразится, и это верно. Но при x=77 y=8 -->  if((77%8)==0) принимает ложное значение, и z остаётся true, что должно привести к выводу строки. Я не могу понять откуда в таком случае берётся значение Y на данном цикли, при котором инструкция if принимает значение true.

Comment: Глупый ответ, но попробуй воспользоваться дебагером с точками отладки. (Мне просто лень думать)